# wpf ViewModel Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, viewmodel, caliburn

I have been trying to teach myself WPF using caliburn. Mostly it's going ok but I have one issue that I can't figure out. I got it yesterday and tried to fix it, I came back to it today and after a lot of time I have got no further. If anyone has an idea of what I did wrong it would be fantastic!

The error is in my view where I define my data context:

The name "TranslatorViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Translator.ViewModels".

My view:

```
 <Window x:Class="Translator.Views.TranslatorView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Translator.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{x:Type model:TranslatorViewModel}"
    Title="Translator" Height="232.895" Width="1030.263">
```

My ViewModel:

```
 using Caliburn.Micro;

 namespace Translator.ViewModels
 {
      public class TranslatorViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
      {
      }
 }
```

My bootstrapper:

```
using Translator.ViewModels;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace Translator
{
    public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
             Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender,   System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
             DisplayRootViewFor<TranslatorViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To set design time DataContext, you need to use **`d:DesignInstance`** mark up extension. See if this works for you:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:TranslatorViewModel}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I still get the same error :-(

Comment: Is that only designer error OR compile time error? Generally designer is unable to pick the values unless you compile it.

Comment: I think it's a compile time error. If I clean the solution and rebuild it, the error comes back

Comment: AHA ! I found the answer.... when I rebuilt it I, I got an error in XAML with my App.Xaml, I hadn't referenced my solution namespace properly. Once I fixed this error, the other error (which was the only error I got yeserday) went away and I can build and run my solution ! Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Great. It worked for you finally. But even in case you want to do design time binding you have to use `d:DesignInstance` and not `x:Type`.